# Why TypeScript ReturnType returned sequence is unstable in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```js
type A = () => 'a';
type B = () => 'b';
type Res1 = ReturnType<A | B>;
type Res2 = ReturnType<B | A>;
```

It's weird that above code run in vscode. I think the `Res1` and `Res2` is different. But they always keep same output. Sometimes they are `'a' | 'b'`, sometimes they are `'b' | 'a'`. I have to restart vscode window or restart ts server trying to get right output. Is this a vscode bug?

[image]
[image]

The sequence is important. That's right when they are used as union type. But I am using it in one situation. For example, as we all know below code.

```
Promise.all([a,b,c]).then(data=>{
  const [a,b,c]=data;
});
```

I am trying to realize something like above code. So, the sequence of union type is very important. If it is normal, can anyone tell me how can I get right sequence like below.

```
type RightType = xxx;
type A = () => 'a';
type B = () => 'b';
type Res1 = RightType<A | B>; // 'a' | 'b'
type Res2 = RightType<B | A>; // 'b' | 'a'
```

Comment: They **are** and **should be** the same. Order in a type union doesn't matter.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166175 We can disscution in here.

Answer (score 0):

`'a' | 'b'` and `'b' | 'a'` is a same type. It just doesn't get ordered by whatever reason.

`|` and `&` for types don't depent on argument order, same as `a + b` and `a * b` for numbers

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDkV4QD4IEbwNwCgD0eEEAegPw6iTpzyaoJK4FFlA :

```
let a: 'a' | 'b';
//  ^? let a: "a" | "b"
let b: 'b' | 'a';
//  ^? let a: "a" | "b"
```

Comment: But why it is unstable? Different time display different result. And I add more describtion in article, can you see again? Thx a lot.